# Awaitility function giving me an error after 10 sec

Tags: java, rest-assured

I basically would like to wait until payment state is refund. I do not want to use thread sleep function. I used awaitility although I am getting an error. Do you have any other suggestions?

**Note:**  I tried with 20sec as well. 10 sec is quite enough for verification.

```
public static Response verifyLineItemIsRefunded(Response rawRes) {
    await().timeout(10, SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> assertThat("text",
        convertRawToJson(rawRes)
            .get("returnInfo[0].items[0].paymentState")
            .toString()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("Refunded")));

    logInfo(String.format("Line item is refunded"));
    return  rawRes;
  }
```

**error:**

```
org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException: Assertion condition defined as a lambda expression in com.vw.ce.api.orders.utils.FulfillmentHelper that uses io.restassured.response.Response Profile not yet updated within 10 seconds.
```

Comment: What are you waiting for? It does look like you wait until the response body changes? But how? Shouldn't you send another request and verify response again within these 10 seconds?

Comment: As far as I understand this function is working like that during the waiting time assertThat function is checking if payment states is refunded or not. Please correct me if I am wrong unless do you have any method in order to fulfill this?